# a powerset define a group?

Tags: group-theory

Let $P(E)$ denote the power set of a set $E$: the set of subsets of $E$. Does the operation $A\cap B$ define a structure of group?

By denition, a group $G$ is a set with an operation $g.h$ (formally, a function $G\times G\rightarrow G$), with the following properties:

The property of the identity: for all $g\in G$, $e.g = g.e = g$.

Existence of inverses: for all $g\in G$ there is $h\in G$ (the inverse of $g$) such that $h.g = g.h = e$.

Associativity: for all $x,y,z\in G$, $x.(y.z) = (x.y).z$.

If the operation $g.h$ is commutative, that is, if $g.h = h.g$ for all $h,g\in G$ then the group is said to be abelian.

Τhanks in advanced!

Comment: How do you add sets?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265834/abelian-finite-groups-basic  i read this post and i really gt confused ..

Comment: thanks in advance for any comment !

Comment: If with $A+B$ you mean that union of sets, then the answer is no. The unity if exists can only by $\emptyset$, but then there does not have to exist an inverse element. Indeed, if $A\neq \emptyset$ then you cannot find $B$ such that $A+B = \emptyset$.

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$

Comment: @AviSteiner: Please don't bite then newcomers.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick (hinted, rather than explicitly answered, since it makes a good lesson) walkthrough to answering the original question of whether the intersection operation defines a group:

1. If the operation has an identity — that is, an element $e\in P(E)$ (or, equivalently, $e\subseteq E$) such that for all sets $s\subseteq E$, $e\bigcap s=s$ — then what must that identity be?  (hint: try taking $s=E$; then your $e$ must satisfy $e\bigcap E=E$.  What is $s\bigcap E$ for any set $s$?)
2. Given the identity $e$ that you found in step 1, can you show that for every $a$ there's a $b$ such that $a\bigcap b=e$?  Or can you find an $a$ for which $a\bigcap b$ can never be $e$ for any $b$?  (Hint: what happens if $a=\emptyset$?)

Answer (score 3):

If you use symmetric difference $A\Delta B = (A\cup B) - (A\cap B)$, then yes.

Comment: Since you get an abelian group (where $-$ will have a meaning), it might be a good idea to not use $-$ for set difference in the definition.

Comment: +1 Adding for whoever may be interested: the symmetric difference makes P(E)  not only a group but in fact a $2$− elementary one: every non-trivial element is its own inverse or what's the same: 
$$AΔA=∅$$

Comment: @DonAntonio: thanks, better now (+1)!

Comment: thanks for your help and especially the user for the better picture of my question!i know that we are in a group so we have to respect the rules of the group but i am not familiar  with latex:(.Anyway,you are very helpfull all of you!

Comment: It is not said why the answer to the only question in the OP is no

Answer (score 1):

The operation is closed, associative and has identity the whole set $E$. But for $A$ a proper subset of $E$, we get $A\cap B\ne E$ for every subset $B$. So no, $(P(E),\cap)$ doesn't define a group structure: it's just a (commutative, non-cancellative) monoid with identity $E$ (which is also the only invertible element).